# Is this close reason right?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

[Linked list vs array performance for RemoveAt() function [closed]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58886/linked-list-vs-array-performance-for-removeat-function)

This question was closed with a custom close reason.  The comment left for the custom close reason was:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about reviewing and improving code, it's about analyzing a specific aspect of it.

Yet there are plenty of on-topic questions that ask reviewers to analyze a specific part of the code.  That doesn't mean the rest of the code isn't fair game to review--it just means that's the code that the asker is most interested in having reviewed.

If anything, this question *might* be closed for this reason:

> Questions must involve real code that you own or maintain. **Questions seeking an explanation of someone else's code are off-topic.** Pseudocode, hypothetical code, or stub code should be replaced by a concrete example.

Because it seems to be asking for an explanation... but it doesn't appear that the asker is asking for an explanation of *someone else's code*.

However, he does seem to be looking for an explanation of his own code, which seems odd.  But maybe a good fit for StackOverflow?

I'm not suggesting that the question should be re-opened and re-closed just for the sake of getting the close reason right--instead, I'm looking for a discussion about this question to see whether we got it right.

What should the appropriate action for this question have been?

- Leave open as on-topic.
- Migrate to StackOverflow.
- Close using the **Questions seeking an explanation of someone else's code** close reason
- Close using some other existing (non-custom close reason)
- The appropriate action was taken--closing using this custom close reason

Answer (score 4):

You have a really long question with a really short title. The text in your question is a bunch of discussion, but, your title is:

> Is this close reason right?

The close reason is:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about reviewing and improving code, it's about analyzing a specific aspect of it.

### Is it right?

The closed question presented two different code items, and then specifically asked:

> Shouldn't the linked list Remove at() function be faster as it avoids Array.Copy in array?

The above is requesting an analysis of the algorithm, and not looking for a review for how to implement the algorithm with better, cleaner code.

### Yes, the close reason is close enough to right for engineering purposes.

There is no request for a review, and there is only one request which is to understand code why the code is 'slow'.

Just because there is no pre-canned off-topic reason that applies to this particular case, does not mean that the question is on topic.